# git clone is throwing repository not found error

Tags: github, git-clone, git-remote

While trying to clone my private repository, I'm getting the following error

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/kefitech/qp-guard.git/' not found
```

I have done some googling but unable to solve the issue.

Steps completed

```
1. config --global user.name and password is set using terminal (windows cmd)
2. git remote -v
```

git remote -v is returning an error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

So, tried set the remote URL to my repository using the command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<my-user>@github.com/<my-org>/qp-guard.git
```

Bur this also returning the same error returned by git remote -v command

Please note that:

```
1. I'm a collaborator 
2. I can clone any public repos 
3. I have not used git client (terminal, cmd) for a long time but it was working before.
```

Looking forward to any pointers to solve this issue.

Comment: Try navigating to your repository on github and copying the link to the clone command from the "code" button at the top right of the page, in case you are missing a symbol or swapped characters, etc.

Comment: @c.fogelklou thank you, but I'm doing the same

Comment: Since the cloning failed, the rest of the steps don't make sense anyway. You cannot run `git remote` on something that is not a git repository yet. One option you could try is to create an empty directory, run `git init`, then do the `git remote set-url` step, and then try to `git pull`.